# Cannot change Angular mat-table column order

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, mat-table

I created a base list using Material `mat-table` as on [this](https://github.com/dnlrbz/angular-material/blob/master/src/app/table/table.component.html) page and and it works without any problem. However, when trying to move the actions column to the end column of the table a shown below, the order remains same at the first column and it does not make any sense.

```
<!-- I move this just below the tr tags -->
<!-- action column -->
<ng-container *ngIf="rowActionIcon?.length" [matColumnDef]="rowActionIcon">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [id]="rowActionIcon" (click)="emitRowAction(element)">
    <button mat-button>
      <mat-icon>remove_shopping_cart</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </td>
</ng-container>


  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

I want also create 3 icons in the Actions column as the last column of the table. Any idea to fix the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not used mat-table, but a quick look [here](https://v7.material.angular.io/components/table/examples) tells me that the order depends on the definition of the row.

```
<!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->
```

I think you need to change the order in your [table.component.ts](https://github.com/dnlrbz/angular-material/blob/master/src/app/table/table.component.ts#L41)
to `this.displayedColumns = [...columnNames, this.rowActionIcon]`

Comment: What about creating multiple icons under single column?

Comment: You should be able to add multiple buttons inside the `<td>` just after the current button, and move the click event onto the buttons instead of on the td component

Comment: Definitely, I added extra `mat-cell` and that causes the problem.

Comment: Do you suggest to use `<mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>` or `<i class="material-icons">delete</i>` ? Which one do you suggest? The latter does not have clickable property.

Comment: `<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [id]="rowActionIcon" (click)="emitRowAction(element)">
    <button mat-button>
      <mat-icon>remove_shopping_cart</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <button mat-button>
      <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </td>`
this should work.. you still have to move the click property onto the buttons from the td

Comment: No I fixed it, I just want to be sure what do you suggest as icon in Material table? `<mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>` or `<i class="material-icons">delete</i>`, I meant `mat-icon` or `<i></i>`?

Comment: On the other hand, I think to use 3-4 action buttons side by side on the last column. I can also make something like three dots and open the buttons, or add a dropdown with these 3-4 options. Which one would be better according to your experiences?

Comment: I think `<mat-icon>` should be used, since you are building an angular application.
As for the multiple buttons, it depends on what you are trying to do. The three dots seem like a better option given you have multiple buttons. You could even open up a horizontal list of icon buttons on clicking the three dots.